# on MS Excel VBA. How to use the current (not active) row's value on a range formula?

Tags: vba, excel, this, trim

Lets see. I Have a named range of an entire column, let say A:A named MyColumn.
If I put on cell B1 the formula "=MyColumn" ... it automatically take the cell on "MyColumn" that intersects "MyColumn", in this case, of course, A1.
I can drag and drop this formula filling from B1 to B5 and its values will be from A1 to A5. We are ok with this.

I need to code on VBA a formula using this logic. Using ActiveCell.Row is meaningless for me, because if I drag and drop from B1 to B5... all the cells get filled as B1 like this:

```
Function Test(ByVal a As Range) As String
    Test = a(ActiveCell.Row)
End Function
```

With the above, my results are like this:

```
valor1  | valor1
valor2  | valor1
valor3  | valor1
valor.. | ...
valorn  | valor1
```

The value is fixed only when I select a cell, press F2 and then enter.

What do I exactly intend to do? I need a function that trims spaces only from the right of a cell, as its values are indented but can contain trailing spaces. My actual function looks like this:

```
Function TrimIndented(ByVal tText As Range) As String
    TrimIndented = RTrim(tText(ActiveCell.Row))
End Function
```

After a mild deep research on the web, I only found solutions using "Active Cell", but I found something about "ThisWorkbook" that references THE BOOK CURRENTLY RUNNING CODE, and NOT the active one. I need something like that, but for a cell.

Can you please help me?

==== - Edit

- I need to preserve Leading Spaces.
- Built-In Formula =Trim(cell) trims both trailing and leading spaces
- NamedRangeA can contain any number of values, and RangeB shall always contain the formula ready.
- It is going to be something like a template

==== -

Thanks, and Regards :)

Comment: just to understand what you want: you are trying to copy the value from A1 > b1 and trim the value?

Comment: what is wrong with `Function myFunc(cell As Range): myFunc = RTrim(cell): End Function` then pass in the relevant cell? Perhaps I do not understand your issue.

Comment: if you are only using column A and column b.. how about this pseudo:
select b1: insert formula = Trim(A1): copyDown the formula using xlDown? this way you have the entire column set up showing trimmed valued from the neighbor A cell.

Comment: @krishKM , Yes I need to pass a named range to my function, and the function to take the particular value at it's current row. The function will be on parallel to the Named Range

Comment: @Cygemth: as previous commenter asked, i don't understand why would you want to use vba for this simple task? if you really want to have done it that way follow my pseudo

Comment: @Cor_Blimey, KrishKM The inconvenience on using a simple formula is that the formula trims both trailing and leading spaces. I only need to trim the trailing ones. On the other hand, I can have a variable number of values on NamedRangeA and I need to have all the prepared formulas on RangeB.

Comment: @krishKM it would help me if I didn't need the RangeA values to be Indented :( . Excel only provides the built in Trim() formula, for both trailing and leading spaces, and I need to preserve the leading spaces :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks, that's the issue. I need only the trailing spaces to be trimmed from all the values on A:A to its neighbor B:B range.

Comment: @Cygemth Does your values have any spaces in between? Or is it only a space before and then after the value?

Comment: @CaptainABC Yes, they may contain one or more spaces in between. Will always contain leading spaces as indentation and may contain trailing spaces as garbage.

Comment: + 1 Almost had me!!!

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550924/how-can-i-determine-the-sheet-name-in-a-workbook-that-my-function-is-sitting) shows how to determine what cell called the current running function.

Comment: @Cygemth I said a UDF (hence the vba snippet) using VBA's RTrim function, not a formula using Excel's TRIM. All I understand you need is a straight no-nonsense pass-through of an Excel value to VBA's RTrim. If so then the snippet I posted is sufficient. A UDF is a precisely defined thing that has arguments that Excel can pass in in a formula and returns a result (be it a single value or an array) - it is not a macro and cannot edit a sheet. If you want anything else then I am afraid I do not understand your question, as currently described, so hopefully someone else has helped you. :)

Comment: @Cor_Blimey Thanks, Exactly I am using an UDF, and passing an argument in the form of =UDF(A:A). That's Why I need a way for the UDF to be 'aware' from which cell/row it is being called from. It is not only passing a single value to the VBA's RTrim, but passing an entire column, so when putting the USF on any paralell cell it will take it's neighbor value from the selected column. :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung Oh My! Application.Caller.Row works very well!!!! :D

Comment: @RBarryYoung I think that's the answer I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a UDF like the below.

Note that for a UDF for deployment to a client you should improve its performance on large data sets by loading the range into an array prior to the loop, also consider adapting it to also handle input arrays etc and various other oft encountered types in Excel formulas. This is in order to give it the functionality and performance users expect of built-in functions.

Usage is like:

1. Use on a string: `=RTRIM(" hello ")` (return: " hello")
2. Use on a single cell: `=RTRIM(A1)` (return for A1 = " hello ": " hello") (this can of course be dragged down a column etc)
3. Use as an array formula (select e.g. the range B1:B5, type in the following formula and enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter): `=RTRIM(A1:A5)` (return: an array of each of the cells in A1:A5 RTrim'd in turn (e.g. {" a", " b"} etc)
4. To operate on the intersect of this row with your defined name use `INDEX` to narrow down the range like: `=RTRIM(INDEX(myName,ROW()))`

Sample code:

```
Function RTRIM(ref)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim results

    If TypeOf ref Is Range Then
        ReDim results(1 To ref.Rows.Count, 1 To ref.Columns.Count)
        For i = 1 To UBound(results, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(results, 2)
                results(i, j) = VBA.RTrim(ref(i, j))
            Next j
        Next i
        RTRIM = results
    ElseIf VarType(ref) = vbString Then
        RTRIM = VBA.RTrim(ref)
    Else
        RTRIM = CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrValue)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I like it except because being an array formula (Which in general is awesome), I will need to rewrite (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) the formula if I need to change the number of rows in which I will operate.
Would be great if, instead of looking within the whole input array (which can be very huge as you rightly said) with those loops, it recognized from which cell/row it is being called from. Independently of the ActiveCell. Any idea? :)

Comment: @Cygemth see usage example 4 - that will return RTrim for the row in question

Comment: Oh that's right, It can work also... And maybe If I combine your code with the Application.Caller.Row property... it would not require to nest the INDEX function, while keeping the most of the functionality. It will only loose the Array function... let me try! :D

Comment: Hi Again! Yep It works!! I only substituted the loops with the Application.Caller.Row property as @RBarryYoung said. Thank you both!

Comment: I will add my final code to your answer so it can be publicly available along with my question and your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would this solve your problem?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    With Sheet1
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            .Range("B" & i).Value = RTrim(.Range("A" & i).Value)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

If you really want a function then try this

```
Function Test(ByVal a As Range) As String
    Test = RTrim(a.Value)
End Function
```

And then in Cell `B1`, put the formula `=Test(A1)`. Now you will be able to drag the formula down.

---

**EDIT**

If you still want to stick to your original approach then change your function to

```
Function Test(Rw As Long, ByVal a As Range) As String
    Test = RTrim(a(Rw).Value)
End Function
```

And then use `=Test(ROW(),MyColumn)` as the formula. Now you will be able to drag and drop :)

[image]

Comment: Hahaha, you beat me to it. I was going use `Left(.Range("A" & i), Len(.Range("A" & i)) - 1)`

Comment: Not exactly, because I need to pass the Range or Named Range as parameter for the function so it can be used over more than one range/sheet. However, yes, that's the idea. :)

On the other hand, If I try a As Range and RTrim(a.Value)  I get a (Pound)Value error as a result :(

Comment: @Cygemth: Both the above code is tried and tested :) If you want to use it in other sheets then why not use the first option.

Comment: @SiddharthRout But got to admit that `RTrim` looks more elegant :) +1

Comment: Actually the parameter I am passing to the formula would be more like =Test(A:A)

Comment: Yes I agree on RTrim @CaptainABC :P

Comment: @Cygemth: And that is my question. Why are you stuck to Formula when the SUB will do the same for you? Specially when you know that `ActiveCell` will give you a problem when you drag and drop. At the moment, I can't think of an alternative for `Activecell` in the code

Comment: Because the document is not to be used by me :( . The person wants to "see the result" as he types on RangeA. Isn't there something like This.row or ThisRow or something? 
Also. BRB

Comment: @Cygemth: I have updated my answer. See if that helps :) You may have to refresh the page to see the edit.

Comment: I think the approach `=Test(ROW(),someColumnRange)` is a bad design practice (I realise this does not stem from you, Siddarth). It would be in better conformity of the whole concept of a 'formula' (being nested functions) to have a UDF that operates on the range passed in in the general case, then use INDEX to narrow down said range if necessary like: `=Test(INDEX(someColumnRange,ROW()))`.

Comment: Yep!! Your edit worked very fine, and also @Cor_Blimey alternative using INDEX() works very well. I am comparing the performance of both. Thank you so much!