# Excel VBA "self aware" formula

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry if it sounds like I poorly researched this, but I'm really strugling with Googling this.

How can I make formula that is aware of cell it is located in?
I remember that certain formulas(default ones, written by Microsoft) will use only parameters from same row as the cell this formula was written in, now I need to write one in VBA that can do the same(and more).
There was a specific name to this phenomenon if I would remember the name of it I could probally Google the rest of this problem.

UPDATE

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
Function Row() as Integer
    RowNumber = 'Some code that tells what row is this formula in
    Row = RowNumber
End Function
```

Point being I don't want to force user to enter row number this formuila is in.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551378/109122

Comment: Step 1: Create "Self Aware" Microsoft Excel Worksheet Function
Step 2: ???
Step 3: Skynet

Comment: To be clear, `Application.Caller.Row` gives the row number

Comment: You should use`Long`, as there are more rows in a sheet than an `Integer` can hold

Answer (score 1):

The functions to return a numeric value for a cell's row and column are conveniently

```
=Row()
```

and

```
=Column()
```

These are Excel formula's not VBA

Answer (score 0):

On top of `Address()`, `Row()` and `Column()` functions, if your worksheet is laid out in rows & columns (as it should be), then you can *turn a range into a table* and use *Table formulae* instead - say there's a table with `Column1`, `Column2` and `Column3` headers, and you want a formula under `Column3`:

```
=[Column1]+[Column2]
```

Automagically refers to the current row - and as a bonus, the formula is the same across all rows in the entire table.